# Android: Send email through basic email app from another application in emulator?

Tags: android, email

I have a basic handler set up to call the email application in the emulator and send an email. I've set up the email app in the emulator with my info so it's ready to go. However, when I click the button in my app to bring up a compose window I get the prompt that says:
"No applications can perform this action"

Is this just something you can't do with the emulator?

```
private OnClickListener submitBtn = new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        String emailTo = "test@test.com";
        String emailSubject = "Subject";
        String emailBody = "Some HTML goes here.";
        emailIntent.setType("text/html");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,emailTo);
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,emailSubject);
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(emailBody));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email in:"));
    }
};
```

Comment: Well, what's the code when you click the button??

Comment: Yeah, i guess that could help. Code added.

Comment: Why do you create a chooser? Just start the activity. Android will automatically bring up a chooser if there are multiple options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a third party app such as K9Mail http://code.google.com/p/k9mail/

The code looks fine, you're hitting some emulator limitations...

Comment: Ok, I installed k9mail and it MOSTLY works. Using the code above brings up the mail app, but it only prepopulates the subject. It doesn't put in the to or body.

Comment: k9 might not support those intent extras? Did you try it on a device with the Google email apps?

Comment: Of course, the best thing is to test your app on a real phone in debug mode. K9 is a (poor) workaround, just to show that your send email feature is triggered correctly.

Comment: I got it figured out. It wasn't taking the to field because I had that as a String variable and not a String[] array. Also, in order to put the body in I needed to use Html.fromHtml(emailBody).toString() The toString is what mattered.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
intent.setType( "message/rfc822" );
```

or

```
intent.setType( "text/html" );
```

This will cause Android to show a chooser to the user for all applications that can send these types of messages. The html option may put up non-email apps so I use the rfc822 option.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work in the emulator by configuring the basic email app with a valid email address.